# Taking window value using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium

Using RSelenium to open a site like this:

```
require(RSelenium)
  RSelenium::startServer()
  remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
  remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.adobe.com/") #the site is just an example
```

What command should I use to take in R the results of `window.s_adobe`?

Comment: Why not try it out: `res <- remDr$executeScript('return window.screenX;')` or sth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something in the veins of

```
res <- remDr$executeScript('return window.screenX;')
```